# How to see man page of `read` command when only `read(2)` shows up by `whatis` in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

On Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS, I want to see the man page of the `read` command used to, e.g., split input up into an array in the Bash shell.

However, the `whatis` command displays only this information:

```
nlykkei@nlykkei-Ubuntu:~$ whatis read
read (2)             - read from a file descriptor
```

But the `read(2)` section of the man pages only documents the system call (and the associated C function).

How do I read the man page of the `read` command used in the terminal?

Answer (score 8):

`read` is a bash buitin command. See: `type read` and `help read`

If you want to see `help read` in man page style: `help -m read | less`

Comment: Aren't built-in functions documented using man pages? If not, I wasn't aware of this. Is the `help` command used only to display manuals of Bash built-ins?

Comment: Maybe bash‘s `read` command is documented in bash‘s man page. `help` is a bash buitin command, too. See `help help` and `help` for more buitin commands.

Comment: why do you suggest that bash's read command is documented in bash's man page, when my question says it isn't documented there?

Comment: I said "maybe". By the way bash‘s read command is as well documented in bash's man page.